# Почему const и goto не используются в java?

Tags: java, синтаксис, константа, goto

Давайте поговорим о двух зарезервированных, но неиспользуемых ключевых словах языка Java — [const](/questions/tagged/const) и [goto](/questions/tagged/goto). Почему они не используются? Как я понял [const](/questions/tagged/const) можно заменить на `public static final`, но как быть с [goto](/questions/tagged/goto)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Обновление**

В спецификации Java ([§3.9. Keywords](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9)) указана причина резервирования `const` и `goto`, не связанная с планами на будущее:

> The keywords const and goto are reserved, even though they are not currently used. This may allow a Java compiler to produce better error messages if these C++ keywords incorrectly appear in programs.
>   Ключевые слова `const` и `goto` зарезервированы, хотя на данный момент не используются. Это позволит компилятору Java выводить более ясные сообщения об ошибках если эти ключевые слова C++ будут неправильно использоваться в программах.

Т.о. разработчики Java изначально не имели планов использовать эти слова, а зарезервировали их чтобы отловить ошибки при копировании кода, написанного на C++ (если бы переменные можно было бы назвать `goto` либо `const`, то скопированный код C++ мог ошибочно пройти компиляцию и привести к неожиданным результатам при исполнении). Эта часть спецификации не изменялась с первого издания JLS.

Ниже первоначальная версия ответа, в которой рассматриваются попытки найти применение для `const` и `goto` в Java.

**Многа букав:** `const` и `goto` перешли из C++. Ключевым словам не нашли применения в Java. Функции, которые они выполняют в C++, в Java реализованы по-другому.

### История

Исторически синтаксис Java основан на C++, поэтому разработчики приняли решение зарезервировать ряд ключевых слов C++, чтобы:

- отловить ошибки при копировании кода, написанного на C++;
- использовать их в дальнейшем при расширении языка;
- упростить переход на Java для C++-разработчиков.

`const` и `goto`

Таким образом вопрос сводиться к следующему: «Есть ли в Java необходимость в `const` и `goto` и что они должны делать?»

### const

Одно из предложений ввести `const` по аналогии с C++ можно посмотреть по ссылке:

[JDK-4211070 : Java should support const parameters (like C++) for code maintainence](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4211070)

Предложение было закрыто в 2005 году. По ссылке можно посмотреть разбор, в выводах которого отмечаются проблемы, связанные вводом `const`:

> - Adding const is too late now.  Had this been added from 1.0,   the situation could have been different.
> - Const pollution: the C++ approach requires all const methods   to be marked with a const keyword.  This means that most   methods will have
>     to be marked const explicitly.  This tend   to clutter all methods in
>     C++.
> - Compatibility is a very important feature of the JDK.   Arguably, the collection classes should be modified to   indicate that the
>     elements are const.  That would   require all existing implementations
>     to be updated in   the same way, effectively breaking all existing
>     non-JDK   implementations of the collection interfaces.  Similarly,
>     hashCode would have to be const, breaking the current   implementation
>     of String.

Создание константных переменных/полей в Java уже обеспечивается с помощью `final`. Ввод механизмов из C++ посчитали неоправданным.

### goto

У `goto` плохая репутация (см. «[Go To Statement Considered Harmful](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html)» Дейкстры). В Java имеются альтернативные операторы перехода: `break`, `continue`, `return`, которые покрывают большую часть области применения. Единственный довод в пользу `goto` состоит в том, что в отдельных случаях использование `goto` позволяет упростить код. По-видимому, сторонники `goto` не смогли оказать достаточного влияния на разработчиков, чтобы добавить новое ключевое слово.

Похожие обсуждения в англиской версии:

- [Why is there no Constant feature in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735736/why-is-there-no-constant-feature-in-java)
- [Is there a goto statement in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545103/is-there-a-goto-statement-in-java)

Answer (score 13):

`goto` считается "плохим оператором", ухудшает читаемость и увеличивает запутанность кода, порождает трудноподдерживаемый "спагетти-код" (также нарушает очень важные концепции программирования, можно ознакомиться по ссылке в конце ответа).

Некоторые серьезные люди считают, что ему нет места в языках программирования, и пишут об этом целые книги. Так вот, пока кто-то говорит об этом, создатели Java - делают. Они искренне считают, что без безусловного перехода мир станет чуточку добрее, и по совокупности проблем и преимуществ с ними можно согласиться. [Подробнее](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto#.D0.9A.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B0)

Само же слово было зарезервировано на этапе создания языка, перекочевав из других популярных в то время. Так и болтается до сих пор...

PS: в Java все же есть безусловные переходы, реализуемые через операторы `break` и `continue` с метками. Как часто вы ими пользовались и знали ли об этой возможности вообще (это по поводу нужности этого оператора)?

Comment: Дополнение. В java на самом деле goto есть, просто его использует только компилятор (программист использовать его не может), если бы оно не было ключевым словом, возникали конфликты.

Comment: ну компилятор использует язык низкого уровня, там без безусловного перехода никак нельзя.

Answer (score 5):

Например они могут не использовать, но быть в языке, как задел на будущее, что бы в последующих версиях можно было легко добавить этот оператор и не пересечься с названием переменных/объектов в уже написанном(Legacy) на старой версии языка коде.

В JavaScript, вроде, такая же практика.

Касательно `const`, который можно заменить `public static final`:

Ничего не мншает разработчикам JAVA в будущем реализовать const и добавить так называемых "синтаксический сахар", когда можно делать и так и так, и в итоге программа будет одинаково выполняться.

Например, в C# много синтаксического сахара:

1. Можно объявлять переменные по алиасу(int) или по самому типу(Int32)
2. Есть LINQ, который позволяет в простых случаях обходится без циклов
   и т д...

Comment: Исторически правильный ответ, не знаю почему народ так обозлился

Comment: Не минусовал. Может быть народ агрится на то что в вопросе вопрос "почему не используются", а вы отвечаете на другой вопрос - "почему они там есть/зарезервированы"

Comment: @defaultlocale спорный это ответ. Вы где-то видели планы по введению goto? Я лично не видел, и для меня это очень сомнительно.

Comment: @pavel, Ну microsoft же резервируют коды ошибок, хотя по факту они нигде не используются и нету планов по введению новых типов ошибок. Тут по сути тоже самое. Может понадобится когда-нибудь, а может и нет.