# Объявление констант в java

Tags: java

Есть переменная такой код:

```
final int aaa = 100;
```

Если написать имя переменной большим регистром, будет ли она константой?
То есть:

```
int AAA = 100;
```

Comment: нет...............

Comment: Обычно константы `static final` т.к. они сразу имеют какое-то значение и неизменны.

Comment: ну и можно в этом ответе почитать причины отсутствия констант в java https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/667941/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-const-%D0%B8-goto-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2-java

Comment: Были предложения ввести понятие `const` из С++, но решили не вводить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет. Переменные и константы вы можете называть как-угодно - это ни на что не влияет. Но согласно конвенции принято называть переменные маленькими, а константы заглавными. Если вы не используете ключевое слово final - то это уже не будет константой, так как она может быть в любой момент изменена. Использование final - сделает невозможным изменение (код не скомпилируется):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]